# How to remediate a coal stain cement and cinder block wall

Tags: walls, stain

I have a room in my basement that was used to store coal. The walls (cement and cinder block) are badly stained and still smell of coal.  I have tried power washing and scrubbing with a wire bush to no avail.  I was wondering if I can seal it with Kilz paint or another product.  Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Do you think the smell is in the wood too? (I think sealing the concrete and cinder block may be the easy part.)

Comment: The wood is going to be replaced.  We are putting in a new floor above it.

Comment: Hmmm...replacing wood structure too?